# what happens between willSelectRowAtIndexPath and prepareForSegue? Need debugging advice

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, uitableview

Somewhere in between these two calls, i get EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code=2, address=0xa).

The common explanation for bad access is accessing a released object - I've compiled with NSZombies enabled and that yielded nothing.  I saw one reference to assigning an integer to a pointer...  which I might have done except I've read through all the changes I've made since this morning (when the program worked) and haven't found anything.

The stack frame lists:

```
- 0 objc_msgsend ... this is where the access violation occurs
- 1 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:]
- 2 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:]
...
```

neither of those uitableview methods are public, so i can't override them to see what might be going on.

although I'm an experienced developer I am quite new to Xcode and objective-c, so would appreciate suggested debugging strategies in this environment.

tia.

Comment: assigning an integer to a pointer sounds very promising: this could very well be the cause of your problem. The trouble with these is that they do not manifest themselves until later - sometimes, a lot later. At times, you would not even see a crash. What you changed since this morning could have exposed the problem that has been there all along, i.e. be unrelated to the crash that you see.

Comment: can you please put up the code as well? that would make it easier to debug.

Comment: @Jonathan:  which code?  I've got .5kloc (ish) and not sure which bits are relevant

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: other than printing & desk-checking all my code, do you have any suggestions on how to debug this?  I've broken up a bunch of compound statements to force type checking; nothing so far... :(

Comment: Do tools show you the line where the int to pointer assignment happen? If they do, could you show that line?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - i wish!!  all i know is that there's an access violation somewhere in private uitableview code, which something i've done somewhere else has triggered.  Is there a specific tool you have in mind?  I'm new to this environment - i've learned about zombies & analyze - neither of which have shed any light on this problem.

Comment: Can you try to add a new exception breakpoint to be thrown on all exceptions, so that you can see on which line the app crashes?

Comment: @verbumdei - it doesn't crash in my code.  it crashes in private UITableView code, in between my controller's willSelectRowAtIndexPath and prepareForSegue (it's supposed to transition to another view, set up in storyboard).

Comment: Then I think it will be good to update your question with the code from willSelectRowAtIndexPath, prepareForSegue, didSelectRowAtIndexPath...

Comment: Are you using prototype cells or custom cells and full delegation to configure them and handle selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good thing they don't let one accept one's own answers to one's own question until the next day.  It turns out that although probably a sound change, the change in initialization was NOT actually the culprit.  If I'd taken @jonathan & @verbumdei's advice, someone else might have spotted this.

when I commented out the willSelectRowAtIndex, everything worked OK.  Huh?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

the template code generated had provided a method didSelectRowAtIndexPath, which I simply renamed to willSelectRowAtIndexPath.  D'oh!

tried this instead:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

amazing the difference that one little return value can make.  AAARRRGGGHHH. I lost a day to this!  I'm surprised the compiler didn't catch it, and that the first version of this method ever got called.  But there it is.

I'm sharing this in case someone else who's as lazy a typist as I am falls into the same trap.

Answer (score 0):

Well - I found the culprit, and as @dasblinkenlight suggested, it was upstream from the crash. It wasn't an int assigned to a pointer... and it must be an odd enough type of access problem that the zombies couldn't catch it.

The offensive bit of code was in my table view controller, and was called from its presenting view controller in prepareForSegue:

```
- (void) initWithDiv: (DivisionDef *) selectedDivision
{
    selectedDiv = selectedDivision;
}
```

Originally selectedDiv was declared as a

```
DivisionDef * selectedDiv
```

inside the implementation as I thought it would be private, with the only access through the initWithDiv method.  Even though I later changed this to a property (strong, nonatomic), the program still crashed.  When I changed the line in the presenting view controller from

```
    [(SelectDetailController *)segue.destinationViewController initWithDiv:selectedDivision];
```

to

```
    [(SelectDetailController *)segue.destinationViewController setSelectedDiv:selectedDivision];
```

presto magico, access violation disappears!

The idea for this  struck me when I was studying the "Declared Properties" chapter of the online documentation from apple, and it explained that the setter methods generated by the @synthesize statement take care of complying with the memory management attributes defined in the @protocol statement.

I find it amusing that no matter what the language, memory management lessons always seemed to be learned the hard way!  Thanks everyone for your suggestions, I appreciate the support.